# What's the maximum floor finish thickness or number of coats of polyurethane varnish?

Tags: flooring, floor, hardwood-floor

I read of people using  2 coats of oil based or 5 coats water based.

Comment: Do not think there is a maximum.  There probably is a minimum, but after that it probably depends on how deep your pockets are.  The surface use will also be a a factor.

Comment: *Minimum* of three. The *maximum* is the same number of licks it takes to get to the center of a tootsie pop.

Answer (score 2):

As many as you can stand; or want.

Pretty sure the basketball courts at my school got 9 coats (and oil based was the only kind there was at that point) every summer. I don't think we ever went past 6 coats at home, and that would just be when we got each old floor sanded down, not on a regular schedule.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a maximum. At our previous house we had our timber floors coated and then recoated 6 years later. Both times, they just poured on the varnish and spread it with a broom. It took days to dry.

But it gave a robust surface for 4 kids and cats and cockatoo. Any crockery that dropped was history.

I have seen coffee tables with thicker coatings, they glowed like amber.

Comment: I always thought a very fine sanding was required between coats for best finish.  I could be wrong about this.

Comment: Sanding between coats is a matter of debate among woodworkers. For some finishes, such as shellac, it's completely unnecessary; each coat of shellac actually dissolves a bit into the previous coat. For some finishes, such as water-based poly, it's suggested that a light sanding (followed by cleaning!), to give a bit of mechanical interlock between layers might be helpful... but I don't know if that has been formally tested. Tables with especially thick coatings generally use specialized finishes designed for that purpose, rather than building it up from umpteen-and-a-third individual coats.

Comment: Coffee table coatings are usually epoxy. That much poly at once - good luck getting it to harden.